# How to remove extra information form error message after executing a package body?

Tags: plsql

I want to remove extra information form error message after executing a package body.

Example:

If I run a anonymous block then the error message come like -

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20010: Object ID PE556092 is not Produced by the Template TP000036
ORA-06512: at "EXAMPLE.TESTPROC", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

But i want to show only the below error message:

```
ORA-20010: Object ID PE556092 is not Produced by the Template TP000036
```

Comment: Why would you want to remove that helpful information?  It's painfully difficult to debug errors without line numbers.

Comment: For front end message. i want to show only the error message to user..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to get the Error Code and Message respectively:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Error code: '||sqlcode); 
dbms_output.put_line('Error msg: '||sqlerrm);
```

Read more about [SQLERRM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm#CJAJBAJG).

Comment: I can not use the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. Could you please provide any other solution instead of this.

Comment: Which front-end/server-side are you are using? Probably I can help you based on that.

Comment: I want to show this message from a web application. web application has developed with ASP.NET code

Comment: Then it should be as simple as doing this: `catch (OracleException ex)
{ MessageBox.Show("Database error: " + ex.Message.ToString()); }` If this doesn't help, then you can add `exception` block to your anonymous block and return `SQLERRM` value from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by defining an exception and mapping it to the SQLCODE of the raised error.  Then you handle the logic in the exception handler.

Example, here I map to error -20010 (the one you are using):

```
declare
   err_obj_not_produced   exception;
   pragma exception_init (err_obj_not_produced, -20010);

   l_object               varchar2 (50);
   l_template             varchar2 (50);
begin
   run_your_code ('With values');
exception
   when err_obj_not_produced then
      return 'Object ID ' || l_object || ' is not Produced by the Template ' || l_template;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one way to hide information about previous errors. Suppose you have two procedures:

```
create or replace procedure proc1 is
begin
  raise no_data_found;
end;
/

create or replace procedure proc2 is
begin
  proc1;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    raise_application_error(-20010, 'There is no spoon, Neo.');
end;
/
```

when you run a block in SQL*Plus, you get:

```
SQL> begin
  proc2;
end;
/

begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20010: There is no spoon, Neo.
ORA-06512: at "DEV.PROC2", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

You can change `proc2` like this:

```
create or replace procedure proc2 is
begin
  proc1;
end;
/
```

And call it like this with desired result:

```
SQL> begin
  begin
    proc2;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      raise_application_error(-20010, 'There is no spoon, Neo.', false);
  end;
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
end;
/

ORA-20010: There is no spoon, Neo.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This example shows how third parameter of `raise_application_error` procedure works. If you pass `false`, procedure deletes information about previously raised exceptions from error stack. It also will be impossible to get this information using `dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace`.
As Jon Heller noticed in comments, hiding information about exceptions is a bad practice (and using `when others then` without `raise` too, as Jeffry Kemp noticed), so, I hope you know what you are doing. This way or another, it is a shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: A `when others` exception that doesn't end with a `raise` is almost always bad practice. Doesn't matter how the code fails, the code will report "success".